# wmctrl does not resize my window

Tags: 14.04, window-manager, wmctrl

I would like to resize a web browser to a specific size.

I have been trying to resize my window (testing `wmctrl`) using `wmctrl` but somehow is does not resize it, however the position works.

I tried:

```
wmctrl -r Taschenrechner -e "0,300,200,800,600"
```

I am doing the test using ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Any idea why is this not working? What I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was just resizing my windows - `wmctrl` was the last command I ran!

I ran:

```
wmctrl -r "Ubuntu Web Browser" -e 0,0,0,1280,720
```

and you ran:

```
wmctrl -r Taschenrechner -e "0,300,200,800,600"
```

My suggestion would be to lose the `""` around the sizes, and (maybe) add quotes to the window name:

```
wmctrl -r "Taschenrechner" -e 0,300,200,800,600
```

---

Just realised your program is a calculator. I doubt you can resize it - I can move mine but not shrink it or enlarge it.

This is standard with most calculator applications (and I wish it wasn't).

You said your main project is a Web Browser - it should work with that.

Comment: Sir, you got it. The calculator could not be resized and changing " " helps. Thanks.

Comment: Working in 2019

Answer (score 4):

The window of `gnome-calculator` ("Taschenrechner" with German locals) is not resizeable. You can't resize it with the mouse either.

You can check that using `xprop`:

```
xprop|grep _NET_WM_ALLOWED_ACTIONS
```

For a `gnome-calculator` window hat prints

```
_NET_WM_ALLOWED_ACTIONS(ATOM) = _NET_WM_ACTION_MOVE, _NET_WM_ACTION_STICK, _NET_WM_ACTION_MINIMIZE, _NET_WM_ACTION_CLOSE, _NET_WM_ACTION_SHADE, _NET_WM_ACTION_CHANGE_DESKTOP, _NET_WM_ACTION_ABOVE, _NET_WM_ACTION_BELOW
```

For a Terminal it's

```
_NET_WM_ALLOWED_ACTIONS(ATOM) = _NET_WM_ACTION_MOVE, _NET_WM_ACTION_RESIZE, _NET_WM_ACTION_STICK, _NET_WM_ACTION_MINIMIZE, _NET_WM_ACTION_MAXIMIZE_HORZ, _NET_WM_ACTION_MAXIMIZE_VERT, _NET_WM_ACTION_FULLSCREEN, _NET_WM_ACTION_CLOSE, _NET_WM_ACTION_SHADE, _NET_WM_ACTION_CHANGE_DESKTOP, _NET_WM_ACTION_ABOVE, _NET_WM_ACTION_BELOW
```

Notice the missing `_NET_WM_ACTION_RESIZE` for gnome-calculator`